# VMware network connection

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I have Windows 7 installed on VMware Workstation 9 on computer. Is it possible to connect to this virtual Windows from the second computed for using? If so then do I need to have Windows on the second computer too to use the virtual one via RDC or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think this should be a problem. You can bridge the network adapter of the virtual machine to your host machine. That way, the VM will get an IP on your network.

You can connect to this VM using that ip address from any computer as you would from a normal computer as long as the OS has support for a Remote Desktop client. As far as i know, all major OS like Linux, Mac OS etc support RDP. So OS should not be an issue too.

In case you want to connect from outside network, you can set a Port forward from your router for the RDP port to your VM.

Comment: Is it possible only using RDC or maybe I can setup second computer to boot from the VM ?

Comment: I think remote desktop is your best option.